# Finding an existing website's icons that use the CSS 'content' property

Tags: html, css, icons

There is a requirement to reproduce/use various icons from an existing WordPress site (no copyright issues - it's a site owned by our company). Here's an example of the code it uses:

```
<ul class="et-social-icons">
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-facebook">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/etc/" class="icon">
            <span>Facebook</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Inspecting the `a` element with Firebug gives me:

```
.et-social-facebook a.icon::before {
    content: "";
}
```

I've searched all the referenced CSS files for ".png", "sprite", etc., but still cannot for the life of me find how this icon is being displayed.

How can I reproduce it?

Comment: it'll be a font file - probably something like font awesome where icons are done as fonts

Comment: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/elegant-icon-font

Comment: @mplungjan, just what I was after, thanks

Comment: Feel free to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

the class *et-social-icon et-social-facebook* must be associated with image in css.
The class *.et-social-facebook a.icon::before* that you are trying to access is a specialization of this class

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `content` CSS property is a Unicode character referencing a symbol of the [Elegant Icon Font](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/elegant-icon-font). In this case, it is the character  representing the facebook icon.

The font is a web font included via an [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) CSS rule.